# Tkinter Scale and floats when resolution > 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How do I can get float values from Scale when the resolution is above 1? If I set the resolution below 1, for example 0.9, Scale will give floats. Above 1, and all I can get is integers.

Example code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale(root, variable=var, resolution=3.4)
scale.pack()

label = Label(root, textvariable=var)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I'm using Python 3.4.1 64-bit on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Troubles with the Scale() widget MVC Visual-part

`DoubleVar()` does not allow to control UI presentation ( Visual-part ) of the `Scale()` ( a depth of decimal places ), while a Model-part remains correct ( though hidden, might get inspected via `aScaleINSTANCE.get()` ).

### A workaround mock-up:

```
from tkinter import *                     # python 3+

root = Tk()
varAsTxt = StringVar()                    # an MVC-trick an indirect value-holder
aScale = Scale( root,
                variable   = varAsTxt,    # MVC-Model-Part value holder
                from_      = -10.0,       # MVC-Model-Part value-min-limit
                to         =  10.0,       # MVC-Model-Part value-max-limit
                length     = 600,         # MVC-Visual-Part layout geometry [px]
                digits     =   4,         # MVC-Visual-Part presentation trick
                resolution =   0.23       # MVC-Controller-Part stepping
                )
aScale.pack()
root.lift()
```

Comment: Actually, just adding `digits=3` to the Scale in the question works fine, no need to change to a StringVar.

Comment: @fhdrsdg it is not that easy. `digits` per-se do not fix additional  `Scale` widget MVC internal dependencies ( [px] `length` vs. (`from_`, `to`) range divided by `resolution` steps ). If you try to have both a 6 decimal places displayed and a 5th decimal place as a widget value `resolution`-stepping, a [post-processed] proxy value-holder is a must.

Comment: You clearly know more about this MVC stuff than I do, but when I look at the code in the question, changing the `DoubleVar` to a `StringVar` does nothing, but adding `digits=3` to the Scale gives exactly the intended use. (I can understand that 3 is not always the right number, it should be the number of digits of the maximal number, +1 for the decimal number. But I guess the same goes for the 4 in your example)

Comment: @fhdrsdg my example has just opened the Pandorra box. **`digits=4`** helps to see that it does not ( if it were left as the only step ) alone solve the group of inter-related problems.